# I'm using NGINX as reverse proxy with multiple subdomains. Redirect a subdomain to different port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have NGINX setup as reverse proxy and a wildcard cert from letsencrypt.

I also have Nginx setup to forward all sub domains to one port (8080) of localhost (10.0.1.4). And this works fine.

domain.org
www.domain.org
offers.domain.org

But now I want to setup another subdomain that I'd like to be forwarded to a server running on different port.

messengerbot.domain.org

Here is my current config that works for my setup (without the subdomain messengerbot.domain.org)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name *.domain.org;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  domain.org;

  location ^~/about {
      alias /home/user/domain/website/about;
  }

  location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://offers.domain.org' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';

    proxy_pass http://10.0.1.4:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  location /public {
    root /usr/local/var/www;
  }


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I tried adding the following Server/location block, but it fails.

```
server {
  listen        443 ssl;
  server_name messengerbot.domain.org;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
  }
}
```

How do I redirect all traffic for messengerbot subdomain to another port on localhost ? I do need to use HTTPS for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot the certificate!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you! I think that fixed it. I'll test some more and revert if there are any issues. Should your suggestion be an answer instead of a comment so I can mark it as solution ?